# TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings

Tags: node.js, less

when I write

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.less' >
```

in index.ejs ,my browser work  but  .less not work no style show.
when I write

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' >
```

in index.ejs ,my browser error.The error is :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and  in the cmd show :

```
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at f (path.js:204:15)
    at Object.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:209:40)
    at Object.handle (E:\nodejsApp\jsmoudle\node_modules\less-middleware\lib\middleware.js:128:26)
    at next (E:\nodejsApp\jsmoudle\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
    at pass (E:\nodejsApp\jsmoudle\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:110:24)
    at Router._dispatch (E:\nodejsApp\jsmoudle\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
    at Object.router (E:\nodejsApp\jsmoudle\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
    at next (E:\nodejsApp\jsmoudle\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (E:\nodejsApp\jsmoudle\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:48:5)
GET /stylesheets/style.css 500 12ms
GET /javascripts/index.js 304 11ms
```

this is  package.json

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "ejs": "*",
    "less-middleware": "*"
  }
}
```

I don't know .less can pass, .css can't pass

Comment: What are you passing as `src` or `dest` in the middleware config object?

Comment: Please post your source code.